# How to add another HTML page to .innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here's my code for a section of my page that i want to change

```
let existinguser = document.querySelector('#existing-user');
let table= document.querySelector('#table-contents');

existinguser.addEventListener('click', () => {
    table.innerHTML = '';
});
```

since innerHTML only accepts string, how do i display content from another page
eg. new_page.html using .innerHTML

I dont't know if this will be required but here are the #existing-user  snippets

```
 <div class="col-xl-3 col-md-6">
                                <div class="card bg-primary text-white mb-4">
                                    <div class="card-body">Existing User's requests</div>
                                    <div class="card-footer d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
                                        <a class="small text-white stretched-link" href="#" id="existing-user">View Details</a>
                                        <div class="small text-white"><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

Comment: it is not possible using `innerHTML` either use `iframe` or different `div`s and display them on user selection

Answer (score 0):

You should use iframe for adding html pages

Answer (score 0):

You can do hacky stuff. You can use Javascript to fetch another html.
fetch('new_page.html').then(res=>res.text())  and add the response to the innerHTML.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery `.load(url)` or any other method of Ajax in general.

```js
$(".container").load("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>next content is loaded from another html page</h1>
<div class="container" style="background:#eee"></div>
<h1>previous content was loaded from another html page</h1>
```